# android: No space left on device in /vendor folder

Tags: android, filesystems

I want to push a library into /vendor folder in an android device but it gives an error: No space left on device. I checked with `df -h` and found that, indeed, the lack of storage in /vendor folder what I'm facing. Only about 16M space left but I want to push a library of 32M into this folder. I want to delete some files/folders, but I do not know this folder very well. I didn't see some folder or file names like tmp or cache, which seems ok to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The `/vendor` is a symbolic link to `/system/vendor`;

```
lrwxrwxrwx root root u:object_r:rootfs:s0 vendor -> /system/vendor
```

Hence, if you free up `/system` it shall endue the free space required.